# Include link in angular-ui bootstrap alerts?

Tags: angularjs, escaping, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How do I include links in an angular-ui bootstrap alert?

Attempt:

[image: alert]

[Plunker Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/QkewqbPkuzBvMrePERyV?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="AlertDemoCtrl">
    <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
    <button class='btn' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
function AlertDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.alerts = [
    { type: 'error', msg: 'Oh snap! Change a few things up and try submitting again.' }, 
    { type: 'success', msg: '<a href="">Well done!</a> You successfully read this important alert message.' }
  ];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: "Another alert!"});
  };

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };

}
```

Comment: Will need someone with rep to decode my `![alert][1]` with backspaces

Answer (score 21):

Embedding HTML markup in AngularJS expression is usually not the best approach as this way you won't be able to evaluate AngularJS directives.

Anyway, coming back to your question - there are many ways of getting around your problem. If you are just after displaying links the simplest way to go would be to use the `ng-bind-html` directive (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.directive:ngBindHtml):

```
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
    <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg"></span>
  </alert>
```

Working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ftab0xtcelXcHSZbFRxs?p=preview

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me. Binding it to a span shows no text in the alert area. (and yes, I can see your plnkr working)

Comment: @user230347 Look carefully at the plunker. Did you include `angular-sanitize.js` (inside index.html)? Did you add dependency on the `ngSanitize` module (inside example.js)?

Comment: I have the same problem as mentioned above. I do have angular-sanitize and added dependency ngSanitize. I simply cannot get this working. :(

Comment: This worked for me with AngularJS 1.3.15.

It should be marked as the answer.

Comment: I had a different problem, where I had used `ng-bind-html` on the `alert` directive itself, which obliterated the alert template. The extra `span` solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer above needed required a few more things in order to get working for me.

My alert looks like this:

```
$scope.alerter.add({
    type: "danger",
    msg: "<strong>ERROR:</strong> Unable to load credit care plan. Please contact your administrator."
});
```

After doing the above I started getting the following error:

```
Error: [$sce:unsafe]
```

So I went ahead, and made me a filter to get around the $sce security. I named the filter unsafe:

```
.filter('unsafe', function($sce) {
    return function(value) {
        if (!value) { return ''; }
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
    };
})
```

Then use the filter like this:

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">
  <span ng-bind-html="alert.msg | unsafe"></span>
</alert>
```

My closeAlert function looked like this:

```
$scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: Getting no such error, it just doesn't work, i.e. it works for such tags as <b> or <i>, but just as I try adding something with attribute style in it, it is cut away for some reasons, dunno where this happens.